# Proving $H_n = \{g^2: g \in D_n\} = \langle r^2 \rangle$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

> The set $H_n = \{g^2: g \in D_n\}$ (where $n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \ge 3$)
> is a subset of $D_n = \langle r, s: |r|=n, |s|=2,rs=sr^{-1} \rangle$.
> Prove that $H_n = \langle r^2 \rangle$.

Attempt:

- Take $x \in H_n$. Then $x = g^2, g \in D_n$. So $g = r^{n_1}s^{n_2}
     \implies g^2 = r^{n_1}s^{n_2}r^{n_1}s^{n_2}$. So I need to show this
  is an element of $\langle r^2 \rangle$?
- Take $x \in \langle r^2 \rangle$. Then $x = (r^2)^k=r^{2k}=(r^k)^2$. And $r^k \in D_n$ so $x \in H_n$

Comment: If you start with $x \in \langle r^2 \rangle$, then why $x=(r^2)^n$? It should be $x=(r^2)^k$ for some integer $k$, not necessarily $n$.

Comment: You are right. I'll fix that.

Comment: For your first point, note that $n_2=0$ or $1$. So show for both cases that $g^2$ must be equal to $(r^2)^k$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: I see. I was able to get the $n_2 = 0$ case. What about when $n_2 = 1$?

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Alan Wang's hint, I was able to get to the solution.
Since $|s| = 2$, that means $n_2 = 0$ or $1$.

1. Suppose $n_2 = 0$, then $g^2 = r^{n_1}s^0r^{n_1}s^0 = r^{2n_1} = (r^{2})^{n_1} \in \langle r^2 \rangle$.
2. Suppose $n_2 = 1$, then $g^2 = r^{n_1}sr^{n_1}s = r...rsr...rs$. Since $rs = sr^{-1}$, we replace each $rs$ in $g^2$ with $sr^{-1}$ and eventually, we see $g^2 = e$, which is definitely in $\langle r^2 \rangle$.

Comment: Regarding $2$, note that $rsr = s$ so by induction, we have $r^msr^m = s$ for all $m$ and therefore $r^{n_1}sr^{n_1}s = ss = e$.